# Default AWS Lambda source code for .NET scratch build

Tags: aws-lambda

I am trying to find the code for the default .NET AWS Lambda function. It does not appear to be one of the Lambda templates and I can't see it in the repository.

I'm talking about the code deployed when "Author from scratch" is selected - before any code is uploaded to the function.

Does anyone know where that source is made available?

I am specifically requesting the source of the .NET Lambda which returns "Hello from Lambda!" when the root Function URL is requested.

Comment: https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-dotnet-demo

Comment: Thanks @jatin-mehrotra but I'm specifically looking for the .NET lambda code which returns "Hello from Lambda!" when the root Function URL is requested.

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to locate that template code anywhere other than in the 'Author from scratch' wizard in the Lambda console?

Comment: I don't, necessarily, but I would like to.